# /bin/sh: /usr/jdk64/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java: cannot execute binary file

Tags: java, ambari

I installed Ambari server successfully, But when I try to start that server it says,

```
/bin/sh: /usr/jdk64/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
```

So could you please help me to resolve this.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you have executable permissions for `java` binary? Also you may need to check permissions of parent directories as well

Comment: It might be wrong architecture. You might be running java x64 on x32 machine

Comment: @G.S yes I checked the execute permission. It has been already done.

Comment: From the same user try to run `/usr/jdk64/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java -version` and check do you get any error

Comment: @G.S I got this error : -bash: /usr/jdk64/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java: cannot execute binary file

Comment: Take a look on http://superuser.com/questions/435988/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-cannot-execute-binary-file

Comment: @ponomandr you should just make that an awnser.

Answer (score 9):

It might be wrong architecture. You might be running java x64 on x32 machine.

As @G.S mentioned in comments the same problem was disscussed at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/435988/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-cannot-execute-binary-file)