# Java -version command error, RHEL6

Tags: java, version, rhel6

I've tried to install jdk7 on REHL6, When i checked if it was installed without any error using `java -version` command, i got the following error

```
[root@localhost ~]# java -version
-bash: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
[root@localhost ~]#
```

i've followed [this tutorial](http://tecadmin.net/steps-to-install-java-on-centos-5-6-or-rhel-5-6/#)  to do it.

have you ever get this issue !!

Comment: i've set the JAVA_HOME variable for the current user, then i've executed the java -version command by the current user, but it doesn't work, i always get the same error !!

Comment: Check if you are running the right version for your architecture (64-bit/32-bit) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841222/bin-sh-usr-jdk64-jdk1-7-0-45-bin-java-cannot-execute-binary-file